# reactjs: Does setState() immediately change this.state?

Tags: reactjs

I've experimented some cases in which calling `this.setState({ foo: true })` and immediately checking `this.state.foo` does not return the new value `true`.

I can't tell now the exact case in which this happens (maybe when calling multiple times to `setState()` in the same iteration, I don't know). So I wonder:

Does reactjs guarantee that the following will **always** work?

```
this.setState({ foo: true });

console.log(this.state.foo);
// => prints true
```

Comment: `this.setState` is an asynchronous operation, so there are no guarantees.  They do state this in the official docs.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Answer (score 5):

> Does reactjs guarantee that the following will always work?

No, [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) is *asynchronous* method., if you want to get updated state you should use callback as second argument

```
this.setState({ foo: true }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.foo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done asynchronously. So you may not see the update within the method. Check that in componentDidUpdate.
or you can see the result in the setState callback , like this :

```
this.setState({name: nextProps.site.name} , ()=>{

console.log(this.state.name);

});
```